# Max. power consumption of ATI Radeon X850 Pro graphics adapter

Tags: amd-radeon, power-consumption

What is the maximum power consumption of a graphics adapter with an ATI Radeon X850 Pro GPU?

Proofs via sources (downloadable manuals) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [PCIe slot provides 75W](http://www.10stripe.com/featured/quick/pci-express-2-0.php) of power and each 6-pin power adapter provides an additional 75W. 8-pin connectors can provide 150W.

Since it is a single-slot card with no additional 6-pin or 8-pin power connectors, the max it can draw is 75W.

Edit:
It is important to note that not all x850s, or any model for that matter, are created equally. nVidia and ATI release reference designs for their GPUs, but manufacturers don't need to follow them. If a vendor releases a highly clocked version of a certain card, they may have extra power connectors and a higher power draw than a different vendor's model of the same card.

Comment: The X850 Pro looks like it has an additional power adapter to me. http://www.newegg.com/Product/ImageGallery.aspx?CurImage=14-102-606-S03&SCList=14-102-606-S01%2c14-102-606-S02%2c14-102-606-S03%2c14-102-606-S04%2c14-102-606-S05%2c14-102-606-S06&S7ImageFlag=2&Item=N82E16814102606

Comment: You linked to the AGP version of the card. AGP slots cannot provide 75W by themselves, thus the need for the additional 4-pin connector. The PCIe version of the card does not have this AFAIK.